# Finite-index subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Assume that $n=[G:H]<\infty$. Then there is a subgroup $N$ of $H$ which is normal in $G$ and such that $[G:N]\leq n!$. Is this tight? More precisely:

> Is there a group $G$ with a finite index subgroup $H$ (write $n=[G:H]$) such that for every subgroup $N$ of $H$ which is normal in $G$ we have $[G:N]\geq n!$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's tight.

Just consider $G = S_{n}$ and $H = S_{n-1}$.

$H$ has index $n$ in $G$. The only normal subgroups of $G$ are $\{1\}, A_{n}, S_{n}$. Clearly $S_{n}$ is not contained in $S_{n-1}$, and $A_{n}$ has index $2$, and so it is contained in $H$ only when $n = 2$ and $\{1\} = A_{2}$. So the only possible $N$ is $\{ 1 \}$.

(When $n = 4$ the group $S_{4}$ has also a normal subgroup $V$ of order $4$, but this intersects trivially with $S_{3} \le S_{4}$.)

Comment: "the index of the later two is two small" - I find it clearer to say that "the latter two are not contained in $H$".

Comment: @pragmaonce, you are probably right, +1 to your comment. I will edit, thanks.

Comment: thank you for +1 and for your answer. i should register and get more points to be able to upvote.

Comment: @pragmaonce, you need reputation $\ge 15$ to be able to upvote, you're nearly there!

Comment: now i'm there :)